# How to convert Nginx config to Apache2 for Modoboa

Tags: nginx, apache2

I am trying to setup Modoboa and can't get the new admin page working because it needs this config which is in Nginx but I am using Apache2 can anyone help me with this config

https://modoboa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade.html?highlight=new-admin#new-admin-interface

```
location ^~ /new-admin {
    alias  /srv/modoboa/instance/frontend/;
    index  index.html;

    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but this works.

```
Alias /new-admin /home/modoboa/instance/frontend/
<Directory /home/modoboa/instance/frontend>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```